# "UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name ..." when running unit test on controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc, microservices

So I have a controller class:

```
package microservices.book.multiplication.controller;

import microservices.book.multiplication.domain.MultiplicationResultAttempt;
import microservices.book.multiplication.repository.MultiplicationResultAttemptRepository;
import microservices.book.multiplication.service.MultiplicationService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


@RestController("MultiplicationResultAttemptController")
@RequestMapping("/results")
final class MultiplicationResultAttemptController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultiplicationResultAttemptController.class);

    private final MultiplicationService multiplicationService;

    private final MultiplicationResultAttemptRepository attemptRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MultiplicationResultAttemptController(MultiplicationService multiplicationService,
                                                 MultiplicationResultAttemptRepository attemptRepository) {
        this.multiplicationService = multiplicationService;
        this.attemptRepository = attemptRepository;
    }

}
```

And the relative test class is:

```
package microservices.book.multiplication.controller;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import microservices.book.multiplication.domain.Multiplication;
import microservices.book.multiplication.domain.MultiplicationResultAttempt;
import microservices.book.multiplication.domain.User;
import microservices.book.multiplication.service.MultiplicationService;
import org.assertj.core.util.Lists;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.json.JacksonTester;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;


import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = MultiplicationResultAttemptController.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class MultiplicationResultAttemptControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    MultiplicationService multiplicationService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    private JacksonTester<MultiplicationResultAttempt> jsonResult;
    private JacksonTester<MultiplicationResultAttempt> jsonResponse;
    private JacksonTester<List<MultiplicationResultAttempt>> jsonResultAttemptList;

    @BeforeAll
    void initAll(){
        JacksonTester.initFields(this, new ObjectMapper());
    }

    @Test
    public void postResultReturnCorrect() throws Exception{
        genericParameterizedTest(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void postResultReturnNotCorrect() throws Exception{
        genericParameterizedTest(true);
    }

    void genericParameterizedTest(final Boolean correct) throws Exception{
        given(multiplicationService.checkAttempt(any(MultiplicationResultAttempt.class))).willReturn(correct);
        User user = new User("Smith");
        Multiplication multiplication = new Multiplication(50,70);
        MultiplicationResultAttempt attempt = new MultiplicationResultAttempt(user, multiplication, 3500, false);

        // when
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mvc.perform(
                post("/results").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                        content(jsonResult.write(attempt).getJson())).
                andReturn().getResponse();

        // then
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        assertThat(response.getContentAsString()).isEqualTo(
                jsonResponse.write(new MultiplicationResultAttempt(attempt.getUser(),
                        attempt.getMultiplication(),
                        attempt.getResultAttempt(),
                        correct)).getJson());
    }

    @Test
    public void getUserStats() throws Exception {
        // given
        User user = new User("john_doe");
        Multiplication multiplication = new Multiplication(50, 70);
        MultiplicationResultAttempt attempt = new MultiplicationResultAttempt(user, multiplication, 3500,true);
        List<MultiplicationResultAttempt> recentAttempts = Lists.newArrayList(attempt, attempt);
        given(multiplicationService.getStatsForUsers("john_doe")).willReturn(recentAttempts);


        // when
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mvc.perform(
                get("/results").param("alias", "john_doe")).andReturn().getResponse();

        // then
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        assertThat(response.getContentAsString()).isEqualTo(jsonResultAttemptList.write(recentAttempts).getJson());
    }
}
```

When I run this test class I get the error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: microservices.book.multiplication.controller.MultiplicationResultAttemptControllerTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.715 s <<< FAILURE! - in microservices.book.multiplication.controller.MultiplicationResultAttemptControllerTest
microservices.book.multiplication.controller.MultiplicationResultAttemptControllerTest  Time elapsed: 2.715 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MultiplicationResultAttemptController' defined in file [C:\Users\pinguino\Desktop\Programming\social-multiplication\social-multiplication\target\classes\microservices\book\multiplication\controller\MultiplicationResultAttemptController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'microservices.book.multiplication.repository.MultiplicationResultAttemptRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'microservices.book.multiplication.repository.MultiplicationResultAttemptRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Now, I can build the application with success.

The only line where the controller is mentioned in the test class is as parameter to the `@WebMvcTest` annotation. The repository which can't be found is this:

```
package microservices.book.multiplication.repository;

import microservices.book.multiplication.domain.MultiplicationResultAttempt;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface MultiplicationResultAttemptRepository extends CrudRepository<MultiplicationResultAttempt, Long> {

    List<MultiplicationResultAttempt> findTop5ByUserAliasOrderByIdDesc(String userAlias);
}
```

I've also tried to add `@Repository` on the class but I get the same result.

Comment: In your controller, you require a `MultiplicationResultAttemptRepository`, but the only bean you've mocked is a MultiplicationService.  Add a MockBean of type `MultiplicationResultAttemptRepository` and you should be good.  This does beg the question, though, if you have a service layer, why would you be accessing your repository directly from the controller?

Comment: I hope you have added H2 dependency in pom.xml and also added application.properties file in test/resources folder?